# incorporating an animation class into level one of a game

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, paintcomponent

I have created this very simple animation class with a timer that is supposed to make a rectangle move across the screen:

```
package NinjaChefGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Animation extends JPanel implements  ActionListener{
    Timer tm = new Timer (5,this);
    int x= 0,velx=2;
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor  (Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x,30,50,30);

        tm.start();
    }
    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
        x=x+velx ;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

here is my level one class:

```
package NinjaChefGame;

import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;
import city.cs.engine.*;

public class DemoWorld extends GameHub {

private Ant  ant;
private Ant  anttwo;
private Ant  antthree;
private Ant  antfour;
private Ant  antfive;
private Ant  antsix;
private final static int NUM_ANTS =2;
private final static int NUM_ANTSTWO =2;
private SoupBowlOne soupbowlone;
private Fixture fixture;
private World world;

public void populate(Demo demo) {
    super.populate(demo);


   {   
      Shape floorshape = new BoxShape(20f, 0.5f);
      Body floor = new StaticBody(this, floorshape);
      floor.setPosition(new Vec2(0f, -15.5f));
     }   
   {  

      Shape shapeplatformleft = new BoxShape(15.5f, 0.5f);
      Body platformleft = new StaticBody(this, shapeplatformleft);
      platformleft.setPosition(new Vec2(-19.5f, 0.5f));
      platformleft.setAngleDegrees(90); 
     }
   {
      Shape shapeplatformright = new BoxShape(15.5f, 0.5f);
      Body platformright = new StaticBody(this, shapeplatformright);
      platformright.setPosition(new Vec2(19.5f, 0.5f));
      platformright.setAngleDegrees(90);

    }

   {
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ANTS; i++) {
            Body ant  = new Ant(this);
            ant.setPosition(new Vec2(i * 4 - 8, -14));
            ant.addCollisionListener(new Collect(getCharacter())); 
      //chef = new Chef(this); 
      //chef.setPosition(new Vec2(-16f, -13f)); 

    }  

       for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ANTSTWO; j++) {
            Body anttwo  = new Ant(this);
            anttwo.setPosition(new Vec2(j * 4 - -6, -14));
            anttwo.addCollisionListener(new Collect(getCharacter()));
    } 
       {

      soupbowlone = new SoupBowlOne(this);
     soupbowlone.setPosition(new Vec2(0f, -11.5f));
     soupbowlone.addCollisionListener(new SoupBowlLost (getCharacter()));
   }
   {    
    Animation t = new Animation();    
   } 
}
}
public Vec2 startPosition() {
    return new Vec2(-15, -13);
}

@Override
public Vec2 doorPosition() {
    return new Vec2(16f, -13.5f);
}

@Override
public boolean isCompleted() {
    return getCharacter().getCount() == NUM_ANTS + NUM_ANTSTWO;
}
}
```

how do I incorporate this animation class into my level one? as in make the rectangle do its animation across the screen in level 1? as you can see I have tried making the simple constructor "Animation t= new Animation" but it has not worked.i am a complete noob and I do apologise.

this class contains the JFrame information:

```
package NinjaChefGame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import city.cs.engine.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class Demo {

    private UserView view;
    private DemoWorld demoworld;
    private GameHub world;
    private int level;
    private Controller controller;
    private Demo demo;

    public Demo() {

        level = 1;
        world = new DemoWorld();
        world.populate(this);

        Character chef = world.getCharacter();

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chefninjagame");

        view = new UserView (world,800,640);
        frame.add(view);

        UserView wideView = new UserView(world, 500, 100);
        wideView.setZoom(4);

        frame.add(wideView, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        CollectedLabel scoreLabel = new CollectedLabel(chef);
        frame.add(scoreLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chef.addChangeListener(scoreLabel);

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Menu");
        Container buttons = new ControlPanel();
        window.add(buttons, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JLabel versionLabel = new JLabel();
        versionLabel.setText("Version 4.0");
        window.add(versionLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        window.pack();
       window.setVisible(true);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        frame.add(view);

        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);

    // JFrame debugView = new DebugViewer(world, 500, 500);

        frame.addKeyListener(new Controller(world.getCharacter()));
        controller = new Controller(world.getCharacter());
       frame.addKeyListener(controller);

         world.start();
    }

    public Character getCharacter() {
        return world.getCharacter();
    }

    public boolean isCurrentLevelCompleted() {
        return world.isCompleted();
    }

    public void goNextLevel() {

        if (level==1){

            world.setPaused(true);

            world = new DemoWorldLevelTwo();

            world.populate(this);

            controller.setBody(world.getCharacter());


            view.setWorld(world);

            world.start();

            level=2;
       }
       else if(level==2){

            world.setPaused(true);    

            world = new DemoWorldLevelThree();

            world.populate(this);

            controller.setBody(world.getCharacter());

            view.setWorld(world);

            world.start();
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Dont start the timer in the paintComponent method. Do it in the constructor. And use logical code indentation

Comment: how would I start the timer in the constructor?

Comment: First do you know what a constructor is? If not, do a quick google search

Comment: yes there is a constructor in my level 1 class "Animation= new Animation()" how do I bring the timer in to this constructor?

Comment: Ok you obviously don't know what a constructor is. You may have to go over some Java basics. I would strongly recommend it before getting any deeper in GUI programming

Comment: i will do i just need to get this particular program done within three days im in a massive rush. do apologise.

Comment: A hint: A panel is not good by itself. It needs to be added (at the very least) to a top level container like JFrame.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: all the JFrame information is in this class which contains all the "spine" code that's in all three levels.

Comment: So add it to the frame. If you don't know how to add a panel to a frame, I'm sorry but I can't help you any further. You are trying to run before you walk

Comment: when i mean "this class" i mean the freshly added class in my question (just edited). could i put the constructor with the JFrame information which informs all the levels or would i actually put all the code from the class in with the JFrame information

Comment: Honestly this question is nothing more than a wall of code to me, with a poor description, I have no idea what you're trying to do. If you want a better answer, simplify the code to the simplest possible case that highlights your problem. See [how to write an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then fix your question.

Comment: i have the class "animation" which extends JPanel. could i create the JFrame for it in the "animation" class and then create an object for the class in my level one class?.

Comment: ive worked out how to do it, the animation does work in the main JFrame of my class. the screen is flickering majorly though any ideas?.